"y" au lieu de "de" avec l'infinitif
Je souhaite qu'on m'excuse d'avoir écrit cette question en français, encore que je ne puisse m'exprimer correctement en cette langue. J'ai trouvé le règle suivant dans un vieux livre de grammaire:

Seras-tu forcé d'apprendre le latin?; Oui, j'y serai forcé.

À savoir qu'on emploie "y" même si le verbe utilise "de". Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Y est obligatoire à cause de la préposition de. Devras-tu apprendre le latin? - Oui, je le devrai..

Excuse refusée! Ecrire cette question en français n'est pas une faute, il n'y a rien à excuser. Bienvenue sur fr.SE cela dit.

Il faut d'abord mentioner que forcer, comme un certain nombre de verbes, peut construire l'infinitif complément avec à ou de indifféremment. Pour certains verbes il y a parfois une nuance de sens selon la préposition, cette nuance n'est pas vraiment perçue pour forcer.

Des grammairiens ont essayé d'indiquer une nuance de sens entre forcer à et forcer de suivis d'un infinitif. Mais l'usage des auteurs ne permet aucune distinction réelle1.

Ce qui nous intéresse ici c'est que le verbe est être forcé, c'est à dire à la voix passive.

Au passif, contraint, forcé, obligé construisent de préférence l'infinitif complément avec à quand ils ont réellement la valeur verbale, notamment quand ils ont un complément d'agent ; ils le construisent avec de quand ils sont pris adjectivement2.

À la forme active on rencontre beaucoup plus fréquemment à que de3. Effectivement il me semble plus naturel de dire « Je serai forcé d'apprendre le latin » que « Je serai forcé à apprendre le latin », mais l'emploi de à serait correct aussi.
Le fait que être forcé de soit employé dans la question de l'extrait que tu donnes, n'oblige pas à l'emploi de en dans la réponse (c'est un dialogue et pas un exercice de grammaire). Personnellement il me semble plus naturel, et c'est certainement beaucoup plus courant, de dire « j'y suis forcé » que de dire « j'en suis forcé »4.
Les deux sont-il corrects ? Je dirais à priori que oui. Voici ce que j'ai trouvé5  à propos de l'exemple « j’en suis forcé (de partir) » :

Intuitivement, il nous semble qu’il est plus naturel de dire j’y suis forcé et j’y suis obligé mais nous gardons la pronominalisation en en , plus adéquate avec la préposition de.


1 Littré mentionné par Grevisse.
2 Grevisse dans Le bon usage.
3  Dans son entrée pour forcer, le  TLF (IV, A., 1.a) signale : 70 % pour à, 30 % pour de dans le corpus littér. TLF. 
4 Les exemples avec y pullulent, j'ai vraiment eu du mal à en trouver avec en. En voici un trouvé sur un forum : j'en serai forcé un jour ou l'autre. 
5 La préposition entre structure syntaxique et résolution sémantique : le cas des compléments prépositionnels de verbes construits avec la préposition à par Leila Mekannez, thèse de doctorat, 2017, note de bas de page, p.97)

J'en suis forcé de partir? C'est pas un zéro en rédaction, ça?

@Frank: En remplace généralement de et y remplace à donc on ne peut pas mettre un zéro à un J'en suis forcé construit à partir de Je suis forcé de partir comme Je suis forcé à partir donne J'y suis forcé, même si l'usage préfère y dans les deux cas.

@jlliagre Je pensais à la phrase complète: "j'en suis forcé de partir", qui sonne très mal à mes oreilles. "J'y suis forcé" tout seul ne pose aucune difficulté. "J'en suis forcé" - je ne sais pas, mais jamais utilisé ni entendu, ce que supporte la note 4 ci-dessus.

Merci infiniment à tous pour vos réponses à ce que j'ai demandé. Je cherchais des examples dans les autres livres de ma bibliothèque sans en trouver aucun. J'étais au point de le fouiller dans le bon usage, avant d'aller faire des course cet après-midi sans le faire. Je le fais toute de suite.

@Frank Elle sonne mal à toutes les oreilles mais on ne peut pas toujours impunément supprimer les parenthèses d'une phrase en y laissant la parenthèse ;-)

@Frank Problème de présentation. Aurais-je dû recopier toute la démonstration ? Peut-être... Les parenthèses ne sont là qu'en écho de ce que rappelle le pronom, l'intérieur  ne fait pas partie de la phrase émise, la phrase complète est j'en suis forcé, point final. C'est clair quand on lit tout ce qui précède, y compris les démonstrations précédentes à partir de la page 95, qu'il faut comprendre Il m'a forcé à partir →pronominalisation de l'infinitif  Il m'y a forcé.  La solution serait peut-être que je m'éloigne de la présentation de l'auteur, sans en changer le sens bien sûr.

@jlliagre En fait, je reviens sur ce que je disais hier soir. J'en suis forcé de partir peut se dire sans trop de problème, mais dans un sens/contexte différent: Il est tellement insupportable que j'en suis forcé de partir. Dans ce cas, il ne s'agit pas de remplacer un de par ce en, mais d'indiquer la cause.

@Frank Ouf ! Pas de zéro en rédac' donc :-)

@jlliagre Mais dans un sens/fonction/contexte tout à fait différents.
